# Can't send messages in Twitch Chat

Tags: twitch

Why can't I see the Twitch chat and send messages when I'm watching someones stream?
Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's [not connected to a game](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14634/185203)

Answer (score 4):

There are many reasons why you may not be able to post messages. To name some:

- The streamer may have subscriber or follower only mode enabled, meaning you need to be a subscriber/follower to send messages.
- They may have "verified users mode" enabled, which means you must have a verified email address to send messages.  Check your email to see if you have a verification email waiting to be opened by you.
- You may be "shadow banned" temporarily for spamming.

  - I've seen this happen first hand - what it does is let you send messages client side, but the streamer and anyone else in the stream will not see your messages.
- You may be banned from the streamers chat in general.

You can read up on some more reasons and how to troubleshoot them [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Twitch/comments/46soqn/twitch_chat_troubleshooting_guide/).

If you can't physically see the chat as in the entire chatbox is not present, it's possible it hasn't loaded properly.  The link above discusses this, and suggests the following:

> - Refresh the page
> - Disable extensions that affect the site (Adblockers, no script, etc.) refresh the page.
> - Clear cookies and cache
> - Reset your Twitch password
> - Switch to google DNS and restart PC.

Comment: Why would resetting one's password affect their ability to chat?..